# Tesseract OCR Custom dictionary

Tags: dictionary, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to add a custom Greek dictionary to improve my tesseract OCR results, I googled a lot of solutions on how to add a custom dictionary and I keep getting this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Jov.png)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the error?

Comment: @TomSelleck first of all I changed permissions on the files so I can have full control. Then i switched the positions of the files. Then i tried changing the code a bit. but nothing happens.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see what you have done or tried.

You need to update your questions to contain exact input / output of what you have done so others can see what you have tried. From your question, I have no idea what the issue is, what the format of your files is, what your code looks like etc. etc.

Comment: @TomSelleck i am in great need of help here, and I could use some of yours. Is there a way to add me on instagram or smth? nikos_simeonidis is my acc. I would be very glad to talk to you. Thanks